# Is there any way to disable pagebuilder for category description without using xml in magento2?

Tags: magento2, category, page-builder, system-configuration

I just wanted to disable pagebuilder from category description without using ui_component category_form.xml , is there any other way to do that like using plugin/event ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

For that, you have to first override `view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml` in your custom module.

Inside your `category_form.xml` you have to add your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="description" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="50" formElement="wysiwyg">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Description</label>
                <notice translate="true">Note: Keyboard shortcut to activate editor help : Alt + 0 (Windows) or &#x2325;0 (MacOS)</notice>
                <dataScope>description</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <wysiwyg class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
                    <settings>
                        <rows>8</rows>
                        <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                    </settings>
                </wysiwyg>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Add the below code for the description field inside **wysiwygConfigData**

```
<item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable Page Builder for the category description in Magento 2 without modifying the **category_form.xm**l file, you can create a custom module and use a plugin. First, create the custom module and configure its **module.xml** file.

Then, create a plugin that targets the **Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Config\CategoryConfig** class. In the plugin, intercept the **getPageBuilderStatus()** method and modify it to return false.

This change will effectively disable Page Builder for the category description. Finally, enable the custom module, clear the cache, and test the functionality to ensure that Page Builder is disabled for the category description as desired.

Here is the sample code(plugin),

**CategoryConfigPlugin.php**

```
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Plugin;

class CategoryConfigPlugin
{
    public function afterGetPageBuilderStatus(\Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Config\CategoryConfig $subject, $result)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I have tested this class is not exists can you please recheck ?

Comment: This class Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Config\CategoryConfig is not exists in  magento 2.4.5-p1 please check

Comment: Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Form check this class

Comment: This class is also not exists can you please check

Comment: Can you please provide proper class ?